# Error playing media in console with jwplayer

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have using jw player in the page but with chrome browser  and internet explorer the video stuck when I skip it ahead but with Firefox it works properly  and this error is shown in console. However, this not happen with html page outside visual studio which seems something between browsers and asp.net

this is the error in console occurs when I skip video ahead or back

The JWPlayer throws this error in the console:

```
MediaError
code: 2
__proto__: MediaError
MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED: 1
MEDIA_ERR_DECODE: 3
MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK: 2
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED: 4
```

I have posted on chrome forums and jwplayer forums bt the answer not helpuful please help

Comment: Can you share any other code? Working with just errors is very difficult.

Comment: <script  type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>         <script type="text/javascript">                                                                              flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",  
                  file: "video/video1.mp4",
  </script>

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Please edit your post, and put the html there...

Comment: this the code I have used and it works fine just for skipping the video ahead that is the problem